# Creating javascript function dynamically in the jsp breaks when special character comes in

Tags: javascript, jsp, apache-tiles

I am creating a javascript function in the jsp which looks like following :-

```
function getBehaviorDescription() {
        var behaviorId = $('#behaviorId').val();
        var description;
        var allocatedPoints;
        <c:forEach var="behavior" items="${behaviors}">
        if ("${behavior.id}" == behaviorId) {
            description = "${behavior.behaviorDescription}";
            allocatedPoints = "${behavior.assignPoints}";
        }
        </c:forEach>
        $('#pointAllocated').val(allocatedPoints);
        $('#descriptionButton')
                .hover(
                        function() {
                            $('#desciptionTooltipText').text(description);
                            $('#descriptionButton').attr('style',
                                    'position: absolute;');
                            $('#desciptionTooltip')
                                    .attr('style',
                                            'display: block; position: relative; left: 214px; height: 40px;');
                        });
        $('#descriptionButton').mouseout(function() {
            $('#descriptionButton').attr('style', 'position: initial;');
            $('#desciptionTooltip').attr('style', 'display: none;');
        });
    }
```

Now when a "" double inverted comes in behaviorDescription the function breaks.

How should i escape the "" in the above code to make the correct definition of the javascript function.

Comment: Are you asking how to escape a double quote in a string in JavaScript? Precede it with a backslash.

Comment: why you are mixing `jstl` and `js` ?